# Cannot start PostgreSQL after installing in conda environment

Tags: postgresql

I am running an `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`. I installed postgresql by typing `conda install postgresql` in my `conda` environment. Now I have postgresql 11.2 installed only in my environment.

My understanding is that the postgres server should start automatically, so when I run `sudo -u postgres psql` I will log in as user postgres. Instead, when I run this command, I get:

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Then I ran only `psql` which yielded another error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Finally, when checking my running processes, there is nothing for `postgres`, so I guess that the server is not running at all.

Now, I can find my way around and start the server eventually, but I don't understand how I got myself in this situation. My question are:

1. Why did the server not start on his own?
2. When installing postgresql, is it good to install it in an environment on the first place, or is it better to use `sudo apt install postgresql` and have it installed on the server globally?
3. How to fix this situation in the best possible way?

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a detailed instruction how to run `postgresql` locally in a conda environment in ubuntu here: https://gist.github.com/gwangjinkim/f13bf596fefa7db7d31c22efd1627c7a - since one can install `conda` (miniconda) under free license without sudo or admin rights in ubuntu or windows or macOS, this is a way to run postgresql on machines without having admin rights on a machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why did the server not start on his own?

`conda` does not install postgresql as a system service. It just installs the necessary software.

`conda` is a cross-platform package manager, i.e. it provides a simple way for, say, a python package to automatically install postgresql as a dependency on Linux, MacOS and Windows (which is great for developers).
At the time of writing, however, it does not also provide an integration of the installed binaries into the service architecture of the operating system (which would depend even more on the details of the operating system).

> 2. When installing postgresql, is it good to install it in an environment on the first place, or is it better to use sudo apt install postgresql and have it installed on the server globally?

If you want convenience, then `sudo apt install postgresql` will be best for you - this is tailored for your Ubuntu version and you won't need to care about starting/stopping the server.

You are unlikely to need multiple postgres installations side by side.

> 3. How to fix this situation in the best possible way?

`conda remove postgresql; sudo apt install postgresql`

P.S. If you don't have `sudo` permissions, installing postgresql via conda can be a good solution - it just means that initializing the database and keeping the server running becomes your responsibility instead of Ubuntu's responsibility. See e.g. [the answer by aerijman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62251420/1069467)

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have sudo permission. Is there any alternative solution installing postgresql through conda?

Comment: If you don't have sudo permissions, then installing postgresql via conda is a good solution. You will just need to manually initialize the database (`initdb -D mylocal_db`) and start the database server (`pg_ctl -D mylocal_db logfile start`). You may want to add the `bin` directory of your conda environment to your `PATH` (but that should happen automatically when you `conda activate` your environment`).

Comment: This is not true. One can run postgresql in conda successfully.

Comment: Hi @Gwang-JinKim, I'm not quite sure which part of the answer/comments you are objecting to. The comment above yours explains exactly how to successfully run postgresql via conda.

Comment: @leopold.talirz ah sorry did not carefully read your comment. I was writing to the answer.

Comment: Cheers, just added a P.S. to avoid confusion about what the answer is trying to say.

Answer (score 4):

[HERE](https://gist.github.com/gwangjinkim/f13bf596fefa7db7d31c22efd1627c7a) is the answer:

create a base database locally:

```
initdb -D mylocal_db
```

now start the server modus/instance of postgres:

```
pg_ctl -D mylocal_db -l logfile start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install postgresql locally in conda - meaning running postresql e.g. with django without sudo/admin rights. I once  (2019) described it in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/gwangjinkim/f13bf596fefa7db7d31c22efd1627c7a

It was quite a lot of trial and error and a lengthy procedure.